# stop ignore message N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.merge-error' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/

Tags: permissions, mv

When attempting to mv the file I get a permission denied. I am trying to fix the message I get when trying to update

```
N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.merge-error' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/'
```

```
mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.merge-error /home
mv: cannot move '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.merge-error' to '/home/20auto-upgrades.merge-error': Permission denied
```

How do I get rid of this message and/or get permissions to delete it. Should I delete this file?

Comment: Smells like an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)-Problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

This is a system file. For renaming or moving such a file you need granted rights.
And you do not want move it directly under /home.

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.merge-error $HOME
```